# SVG width expand when import via Icomoon

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, font-face

I exported SVG file with Illustrator (already "Fit to selected Art"). When I'm importing SVG via Icomoon App I getting this error while others looking good.

[image]

Hope you can help me out. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no error there. IcoMoon places wider icons in wider cells for a better preview. If it doesn't do this, it would have to scale the icon down even further in order to make the icon fit in the smaller cell.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. Works the same.